Strange 7-Zip behaviour on Windows 11
For years, I've stored 7z.exe in a directory that contains many other utilities and batch files. Suddenly, for no apparent reason, 7z.exe failed and continues to fail. Instead of compressing the data as expected and producing a .7z file, it simply does nothing.
I made a new directory, copied 7z.exe to that directory and installed it as the first directory in path. Sanity was restored and the .7z file was created as usual.
UAC on my system is turned OFF; I've run memory tests extensively and chkdsk with no errors. Obligatory virus scans revealed nothing. I run from an administrator account.

So - the fc confirms that the files are identical and c:\batch\7z.exe can be read.
Simply executing c:\bvckupbatch\7z.exe produces a help list - I filtered it for "--" to reduce the output.
Executing c:\batch\7z.exe merely returns to the prompt apparently having done nothing.

I do notice that the C:\Batch one has 7Z.EXE written with all caps. What if you rename it to 7ze.exe and then to 7z.exe? 7z.exe could have something inside it to ensure that the name is 7z.exe but fails that check. also what are the security permissions of C:\Batch?

It should be pointed out it's not actually possible to completely disable UAC on Windows 10+ I don't see an example of your command actually working.  Can you provide a screenshot of that or am I miss reading what you have provided?

also, do you have 7z.dll and the other files in that folder?

After the last few Windows Updates (to Win 10 as well as 11), I've noticed some apps no longer work when installed in Program Files, and the installers are putting the executables in strange places. such as zoom.exe, sumatra.exe and python3.exe in \AppData. At a guess, MS wants apps to be installed only through the MS Store, and is making it harder for traditional executables to be installed.

@LPChip : Tried the rename to 7ze then7z - identical results. UAC disabled, has worked for many years and no apparent problems with other executables in c:\batch. 7z.dll exists only in c:\batch, so is being run successfully from c:\bvckupbatch. Both c:\bvckupbatch and c:\batch are in the path, and in that order.

@Ramhound : Had I said that UAC had been minimised, no doubt this would have raised questions of what exactly I mean and how. Certainly, patches annoyingly occasionally re-impose or partially re-impose UAC but easily removed. Screenshot shows the result  -- : Stop switches and @listfile parsing after having run c:\BVCKUPbatch\7Z.EXE - I filtered out just that line from the syntax report 7z.exe generates if provided with no arguments to minimise clutter. Producing that line indicates that 7z has run. Running from c:\batch produced no output whatever.

@DrMoishePippik : I've noticed some strange shenanigans myself. In the specific case of 7z.exe, there's been no change - has been working for years, then simply doesn't run one day. No apparent changes/re-installs, same version etc. May have been a Microsoft OS patch, but I doubt I'd be the only one affected. I've had a link to a batch file in my startup directory for years which backs up a host of directories. That stopped running. Still chasing why - have found a few solutions but none worked for me - smt about running with admin privileges being disallowed. still working on it.

@Io-oI : Tried that; had no effect.

@lo-ol : Output differed in fields File reference number, Link (ParentID: Name), Creation Time, Last Access Time, Change Time, LastUsn, and SecurityId

@Io-oI : Skipped a couple of questions. The executable is one of several which form 7Zip's compression suite. Each copy of 7z.exe on my machine is a direct copy from that distributed by 7-Zip. If the file, specifically that in c:\batch is renamed (say, to 7q.exe) then it runs as expected. The fault is only displayed when the file is named c:\batch\7z.exe. Each version is identical accoring to fc /b (which proves that both versions can be read & the bytes in each are identical), but only the executable c:\batch\7z.exe fails to run.
